# How to make asynchronous Web API call in net framework4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I want to implement an asynchronous web api call from my asp.net client.

My ASP.NET  code is similar like this

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                     {
                        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);
                        var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/mycontroller/execute/", executeModel).Result;
                     }
```

My Web API code is similar like this

```
public void Execute(Model model)
{
    DoTask(model);
}

public void DoTask(Model model)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { DoIt(model); }).ContinueWith(t => t.Exception); 
}

public void DoIt(Model model)
{
    try
    {
    //My code Here
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

after the post request I want to quit the asp.net call,do some task in asp.net side. 
at same time I want to continue the webapi call in one thread in Web API. How i could implement this?

Comment: You can use [GetAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158912(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SendAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: If I use  GetAsync() and SendAsync() methods, I need to wait for that methods to complete. I do not want to wait. I want to do some other task in ui side.